# How to check number of free INodes in Android

Tags: android, unix, inode

Inside application I am downloading so many files that it seems it can reach the number of files limitation, in other words I am unable to create new file, since system has run out of INodes.

How can I check this limit from Android code or even with some adb command. I know on unix you can use `df -i` command, however it is not possible to do that through `adb shell` since it prints `-i: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I use BusyBox for this, which provides many unix commands and more complete versions of those already included. Once installed, you can issue

```
busybox df -i
```